# Prove that $|(a,b)\cup (c,d)|=(b-a)+(d-c)\text{ if and only if }(a,b)\cap (c,d)=\emptyset.$ ("Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler)

Tags: solution-verification, alternative-proof, outer-measure

I am reading "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler.
The following exercise is Exercise 7 on p.23 in Exercises 2A in this book.

***I want to prove this exercise using only the knowledge up to page 23 in Axler's book.

Electronic version of "Measure, Integration & Real Analysis (20 December 2022)" is freely available from the author's site.

I think the answers at [Prove that $|(a,b) \cup (c,d)| = (b-a) + (d-c) \iff (a,b) \cap (c,d) = \emptyset$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3814400/384082) don't use only the knowlege up to page 23 in Axler's book.***

> Exercise 7 on p.23:
> Suppose $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers with $a<b$ and $c<d$. Prove that $$|(a,b)\cup (c,d)|=(b-a)+(d-c)\text{ if and only if }(a,b)\cap (c,d)=\emptyset.$$

My proof is very ugly.
Is my proof ok?
I want to know a clean proof even if my proof is ok.

We use the following proposition in our proof.

> 2.14 outer measure of a closed interval on p.20:
> Suppose $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, with $a<b$. Then $|[a,b]|=b-a$.

The author proved the following proposition (we call it Lemma 1) in the proof of 2.14 on p.20.

> Lemma 1:
> Let $I_1,I_2,\dots,I_n$ be open intervals such that $[a,b]\subset I_1\cup I_2\cup\dots\cup I_n$.
> Then, $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathcal{l}(I_k)\geq b-a.$$

> Lemma 2:
> Suppose that $[a,b]\cap [c,d]=\emptyset$.
> Then, $|[a,b]\cup [c,d]|=(b-a)+(d-c)$.

> My proof of Lemma 2:
> Since $[a,b]\cap [c,d]=\emptyset$, $c\notin [a,b]$.
> Since $[a,b]\cap [c,d]=\emptyset$, $d\notin [a,b]$.
> So, $c<a$ or $b<c$.
> So, $d<a$ or $b<d$.
> If $c<a$, then $b\not < d$ since $[a,b]\cap [c,d]=\emptyset$.
> So, $d<a$.
> So, $c<d<a<b$.
> If $b<c$, then $a<b<c<d$.
> So, $c<d<a<b$ or $a<b<c<d$ holds.
> Without loss of generality, we can assume that $a<b<c<d$.
> Suppose $I_1,I_2,\dots$ is a sequence of open intervals such that $[a,b]\cup [c,d]\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_k$.
> By the Heine-Borel Theorem (2.12 on p.19), there exists $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $$[a,b]\cup [c,d]\subset I_1\cup\dots\cup I_n.$$
> Let $J:=\{I_i:I_i\cap [a,b]\neq\emptyset, I_i\cap [c,d]=\emptyset\}.$
> Let $K:=\{I_i:I_i\cap [a,b]=\emptyset, I_i\cap [c,d]\neq\emptyset\}.$
> Let $L:=\{I_i:I_i\cap [a,b]\neq\emptyset, I_i\cap [c,d]\neq\emptyset\}.$
> Let $M:=\{I_i:I_i\cap [a,b]=\emptyset, I_i\cap [c,d]=\emptyset\}.$
> Let $I_i\in L$ and $I_i=(e,f)$.
> Then, $e<b<c<f$.
> Let $L_1:=\{I_i\cap (-\infty,\frac{b+c}{2}):I_i\cap [a,b]\neq\emptyset, I_i\cap [c,d]\neq\emptyset\}.$
> Let $L_2:=\{I_i\cap (\frac{b+c}{2},\infty):I_i\cap [a,b]\neq\emptyset, I_i\cap [c,d]\neq\emptyset\}.$
> Then, $J\cup L_1$ is a finite open cover of $[a,b]$.
> Then, $K\cup L_2$ is a finite open cover of $[c,d]$.
> Then, $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathcal{l}(I_k)\geq\sum_{I\subset J\cup K\cup L\cup M}\mathcal{l}(I)\geq\sum_{I\subset J\cup K\cup L}\mathcal{l}(I)\\=\sum_{I\subset J\cup L_1}\mathcal{l}(I)+\sum_{I\subset K\cup L_2}\mathcal{l}(I)\geq (b-a)+(d-c)$$ by Lemma 1.
> So, $|[a,b]\cup [c,d]|\geq (b-a)+(d-c)$.
> By countable subadditivity of outer measure (2.8 on p.17), $|[a,b]\cup [c,d]|\leq |[a,b]|+|[c,d]|=(b-a)+(d-c)$.
> So, $|[a,b]\cup [c,d]|= (b-a)+(d-c)$.

> My proof of Exercise 7:
> Suppose that $(a,b)\cap (c,d)\neq\emptyset$.
> Then, there exists $x$ such that $x\in (a,b)\cap (c,d)$.
> So, $\max\{a,c\}<x<\min\{b,d\}$.
> So, $\max\{a,c\}<\min\{b,d\}$.
> Case 1:
> We consider the case in which $a=c=t$.
> Then, $(a,b)\cup (c,d)=(t,\max\{b,d\})$.
> So, $|(a,b)\cup (c,d)|=\max\{b,d\}-t=\max\{b-t,d-t\}=\max\{b-a,d-c\}<(b-a)+(d-c)$.
> Case 2:
> We consider the case in which $a\neq c$.
> Without loss of generality, we can assume that $a<c$.
> Case 2-1:
> We consider the case in which $a<c$ and $b\leq d$.
> In this case, $c=\max\{a,c\}<\min\{b,d\}=b$.
> So, $(a,b)\cup (c,d)=(a,d)$.
> So, $|(a,b)\cup (c,d)|=d-a=(b-a)+(d-b)<(b-a)+(d-c)$.
> Case 2-2:
> We consider the case in which $a<c$ and $d<b$.
> $(a,b)\cup (c,d)=(a,b)$.
> $|(a,b)\cup (c,d)|=b-a<(b-a)+(d-c)$.
>
> Suppose that $(a,b)\cap (c,d)=\emptyset$.
> Then, $a\neq c$ since $(a,b)\cap (c,d)=\emptyset$.
> Without loss of generality, we can assume that $a<c$.
> Since $(a,b)\cap (c,d)=\emptyset$, $b\leq c$.
> So, $a<b\leq c<d$.
> Case 1:
> We consider the case in which $b=c$.
> In this case $[a,b]\cup [c,d]=[a,d]$.
> For any positive real number $\epsilon$, $[a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon]\cup [c+\epsilon,d-\epsilon]\subset (a,b)\cup (c,d)$.
> By Lemma 2, $(b-a)+(d-c)+4\epsilon=|[a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon]\cup [c+\epsilon,d-\epsilon]|\leq|(a,b)\cup (c,d)|\leq|[a,b]\cup [c,d]|=d-a$.
> So, $|(a,b)\cup (c,d)|=d-a=(b-a)+(d-c)$.
> Case 2:
> We consider the case in which $b<c$.
> In this case, $[a,b]\cap [c,d]=\emptyset$.
> For any positive real number $\epsilon$, $[a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon]\cup [c+\epsilon,d-\epsilon]\subset (a,b)\cup (c,d).$
> So, by Lemma 2, $(b-a)+(d-c)+4\epsilon=|[a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon]\cup [c+\epsilon,d-\epsilon]|\leq|(a,b)\cup (c,d)|\leq|[a,b]\cup [c,d]|=(b-a)+(d-c).$
> So, $|(a,b)\cup (c,d)|=(b-a)+(d-c)$.

Comment: Compare [Prove that $|(a,b) \cup (c,d)| = (b-a) + (d-c) \iff (a,b) \cap (c,d) = \emptyset$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3814400/42969)

Comment: @MartinR Thank you very much for your answer. Axler proved that there exist disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $|A\cup B|\neq |A| + |B|$ in the book.  But at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2063881/384082, the following equality is used: $|A\cup B|= |A| + |B|$ holds for disjoint subsets $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Countable additivity is a *defining property* of all measures: the measure of a disjoint countable union of measurable sets is equal to the sum of the measures. – I don't have that book, perhaps the example is about non-measurable sets and their outer measure?

Comment: I have read up to page 23 of this book. I don't know what "measurable set" is yet. Anyway, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @MartinR I want to prove this exercise using only the knowledge up to page 23 in this book.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $|(a,b) \cup (c,d)| = (b-a) + (d-c) \iff (a,b) \cap (c,d) = \emptyset$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814400/prove-that-a-b-cup-c-d-b-a-d-c-iff-a-b-cap-c-d-emptyset)

Comment: @JMP No. I think the answers don't use only the knowlege up to page 23 in Axler's book.

Answer (score 1):

I improved my proof.

---

We use the result of Exercise 3 on p.23 in Exercises 2A in the book.

> Exercise 3 on p.23 in Exercises 2A:
> Prove that if $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $|A|<\infty$, then $|B\setminus A|\geq |B|-|A|$.

My proof of Exercise 3:

> Please see the following link:
> [Prove if $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $|A|<\infty$, then $|B\setminus A|\geq |B|-|A|$ ("Measure, Integration & Real Analysis" by Sheldon Axler)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4642667/384082)

---

We use the result of Exercise 6 on p.23 in Exercises 2A in the book.

> Prove that if $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$, then $$|(a,b)|=|[a,b)|=|(a,b]|=b-a.$$

My proof of Exercise 6:

> We know that $|[a,b]|=b-a$. (Please see 2.14 on p. 20 in the book.)
> Since $[a,b]\supset (a,b)$, $b-a=|[a,b]|\geq |(a,b)|.$
> Since $[a,b]\supset [a,b)$, $b-a=|[a,b]|\geq |[a,b)|.$
> Since $[a,b]\supset (a,b]$, $b-a=|[a,b]|\geq |(a,b]|.$
> In the above lines, we used 2.5 on p.16 in the book. (outer measure preserves order.)
> Let $\epsilon$ be an arbitrary positive real number.
> Since $[a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon]\subset (a,b)$, $b-a-2\epsilon\leq |(a,b)|.$
> Since $[a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon]\subset [a,b)$, $b-a-2\epsilon\leq |[a,b)|.$
> Since $[a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon]\subset (a,b]$, $b-a-2\epsilon\leq |(a,b]|.$
> Since $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary positive real number, $$|(a,b)|=|[a,b)|=|(a,b]|=b-a.$$

---

> Fact 1:
> If $(a,b)\cap (c,d)\neq\emptyset$, then $|(a,b)\cap (c,d)|<(b-a)+(d-c)$.

My proof of Fact 1:

> The proof of Fact 1 is the same as my previous proof.

---

> Fact 2:
> If $(a,b)\cap (c,d)=\emptyset$, then $|(a,b)\cap (c,d)|=(b-a)+(d-c)$.

My proof of Fact 2:

> We now prove Fact 2.
> Suppose $(a,b)\cap (c,d)=\emptyset$.
> Without loss of generality, we can assume $a<b\leq c<d$.
> Obviously, $(a,b)\cup (c,d)=(a,d)\setminus [b,c]$ holds.
> By the result of Exercise 3 and Exercise 6 on p.23 in Exercises 2A in the book, $$|(a,b)\cup (c,d)|=|(a,d)\setminus [b,c]|\geq |(a,d)|-|[b,c]|=(d-a)-(c-b)=(b-a)+(d-c).$$
> By 2.8 on p.17 in the book (countable subadditivity of outer measure) and by Exercise 6 on p.23 in Exercises 2A in the book, $$|(a,b)\cup (c,d)|\leq |(a,b)|+|(c,d)|=(b-a)+(d-c).$$
> Therefore, $$|(a,b)\cap (c,d)|=(b-a)+(d-c)$$ holds.